# filtrar datos a partir de un sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny

quisiera filtrar una base de datos a partir del minimo y el maximo de un sliderInput y un rango de fechas, para construir una tabla que me muestre por cada especialidad el porcentaje que esta dentro de ese rango en el periodo de tiempo seleccionado. Tengo una base de datos de este estilo (mucho mas grande):

```
    Indicea<-c(1,2,3,5,3,1,3,5,3,6,NA,2,1,1,3,2)
    Indiceb<-c(12,15,12,14,13,16,14,13,15,12,14,13,NA,13,11,12)
    Indicec<-c(100,NA,120,154,125,201,102,150,102,105,140,156,118,113,175,189)
    Especialidad<-c("gato","gato","gato","perro","perro","perro","perro",
            "buho","buho","buho","buho","tigre","tigre","tigre",NA,"tigre")
    Indiced<-c(0.1,0.5,06,032,0.1,0.25,0.23,0.12,0.15,NA,0.25,0.45,1.0,0.5,0.26,0.45)
    Fecha<-c("01/03/2020","02/03/2020","03/03/2020","04/03/2020",
         "05/03/2020","06/03/2020","07/03/2020","08/03/2020",
         "09/03/2020","10/03/2020","11/03/2020","12/03/2020",
         "13/03/2020","14/03/2020","15/03/2020")
  data<-dataframe(Indicea, Indiceb,Indicec,Indiced,Especialidad,Fecha)
```

De esta manera  va mi codigo en el ui

```
     ui <- fluidPage(
     tabItem("IndicesI",
      tabsetPanel(# position= "left",
                  tabPanel("Indices de ingreso", icon = icon("file-medical-alt"),
                           sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                             uiOutput("SeleccioneEspecialidad2"),
    checkboxInput("Todas","SeleccioneTodas/Ninguna",value=FALSE),
                             uiOutput("SeleccioneIndice"),
                             uiOutput("Rango"),  
                            uiOutput("RandeDatedI")                            
                         
                              ),
                           mainPanel(
                             dataTableOutput("summary")
                           )))
            )))
```

Y esta es mi idea del server, pero no hace la tabla como quiero

```
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$SeleccioneEspecialidad2<-renderUI({
    choices <- na.omit(data$Especialidad)
    selectInput("SeleccioneEspecialidad2", "Seleccione Especialidad",
            choices=choices, multiple = T, selected = TRUE )
     })

     BD<-reactive({
        req(input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2)
        data %>%
          filter(Especialidad %in% input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2 )
           })

      output$SeleccioneIndice <-renderUI({
       selectInput("SeleccioneIndice", "Seleccione Indice", choices=
              c("Ments"="Indicea",
                "Fragilidad"="Indiceb",
                "ElixhauserAHRQ"="Indicec",
                "ElixhauserVanWalraven"="Indiced"))

                  })

          output$Rango<-renderUI({
          req(input$SeleccioneIndice)
         minn <- min(BD()[,input$SeleccioneIndice], na.rm = TRUE)
         maxx <- max(BD()[,input$SeleccioneIndice], na.rm = TRUE)
         sliderInput("Rango",label = "Seleccione un rango", min = minn, max=maxx, 
         value=c(minn,maxx))
           })

     FechaI<-reactive({
     BD1<-BD()
     unique(BD1$Fecha)
       })
    output$RandeDatedI <-renderUI({
      dateRangeInput('dateRangeI',
               label = 'Seleccione un rango',
               start = min(FechaI(),na.rm=T), max(FechaI(),na.rm=T)
         )
      })
    BD9.2<-reactive({
    BD9.3<-BD()
    BD9.3 %>%
   filter(input$SeleccioneIndice>= input$SeleccioneIndice[1]  & 
   input$SeleccioneIndice>= input$SeleccioneIndice[1])%>%
  filter(Fecha >= input$dateRangeI[1] & Fecha <= 
  input$dateRangeI[2]) %>%
  count(input$SeleccioneEspecialidad2) %>%
  mutate(percent=round(((n/sum(n))*100), digits=2))->tmpI
  names(tmpI)<- c("Especilidad","N","Porcentaje")   

  tmpI

  })
  output$summary<-DT::renderDataTable({
   datatable(BD9.2(), class = 'cell-border stripe', options = list(
   order = list(list(3, 'desc'))))
  })
  })
         shinyApp(ui, server)
```

La idea es que filtre por la especialidad, luego que por tipo de indice porga el rango del sliderinput y según el rango de fechas que se le de, calcule cual es el porcentaje para esa especilidad que estaba en ese rango.